# Reduce compilation time

Tags: c++, compilation, header, pimpl-idiom

ConfigsList.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <Configs/structures/First/First.hpp>
#include <Configs/structures/First/First_info.hpp>

#include <Configs/structures/Second/Second.hpp>
#include <Configs/structures/Second/Second_info.hpp>

#include <Configs/structures/Third/Third.hpp>
#include <Configs/structures/Third/Third_info.hpp>

#include <Configs/structures/Forth/Forth.hpp>
#include <Configs/structures/Forth/Forth_info.hpp>

#include <Configs/configs_manager.hpp>

namespace configs::list
{
using ConfigsManager = configs::ConfigsManager<
FirstInfo,
SecondInfo,
ThirdInfo,
ForthInfo>;
}
```

**1)FirstInfo, SecondInfo... are some (let not small) types**

**2)ConfigsManager is actually types container like std::tuple.**

That is:

```
TypesContainer<FirstType, SecondType...>;
```

Need to include this file in many other headers, and increasing this file exponentially increases compilation time.

I can't push into this container(ConfigsManager) from the upper headers, so need to instantiate this container from `ConfigsList.hpp`.

Also I can't use pimpl - it encapsulates the ConfigsManager methods for other file in which need to create an instance of the class.

The goal is to use the types container without "re-including" the top headers.

Comment: Not possible, as described.   It is not possible to instantiate or use a `configs::ConfigsManager<FirstInfo, SecondInfo, ThirdInfo, ForthInfo>` unless the compiler has visibility of the definitions of `FirstInfo`, `SecondInfo`, `ThirdInfo`, `ForthInfo` (sic) and the templated `config::ConfigsManager`.   If those things are defined in different headers, your ConfigsList.hpp must include all those headers.

Comment: Would precompiled headers help?

Comment: @TobiasWollgam, what does this mean?) I have already given up and am using dynamic approach(

Comment: Precompiled headers is a compilation step that may speedup the whole compilation process. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header